# checking for substrings in two pandas dataframe

Tags: python, string, pandas

I have two dataframes, and i am using the function str.contains to see if values of column can be found in the other dataframe.

```
for i in range(len(ingName)):
    ingName[i]

#check if the string contains IngName ignoring uppercase, ignoring substrings


df_grocery[df_grocery['[SUB CATEGORY]'].str.contains(ingName[i], case=False)]
        df_grocery['IngredientName'] = ingName[i]
        df_grocery['IngredientID'] = ingID[i]
```

if i specify the row number, everything works fine, but if i try to loop over all the name in `ingName[i]`, it returns back an error that says

```
"TypeError: first argument must be string or compiled pattern"
```

if I do this, it only returns back the last element in the array?

```
df_grocery[df_grocery['[SUB CATEGORY]'].str.contains(ingName[i], case=False)]
df_grocery['IngredientName'] = ingName[i]
df_grocery['IngredientID'] = ingID[i]
```

Does this has anything to do with how my csv file is saved, or how i am trying to achieve this?

Also the console prints this out

```
   246     if not sre_compile.isstring(pattern):
-->247         raise TypeError, "first argument must be string or compiled pattern"
    248     try:
    249         p = sre_compile.compile(pattern, flags)
```

Thanks, and any help will be appreciated.

```
Hey @Tammy, let me try to explain what i am trying to achieve again
A   B
1  Rice
2  Choco

A                           B         
rice with no calries      22222
rice with calories        22222 
Milk                      22212


what i am trying to do is have

A                         B     c    d
rice with no calries      22222 1  Rice
rice with calories        22222 1  Rice
```

i can achieve this using my first function, but the problem arises when i try to iterate over all the ID in the first dataframe.

```
df_grocery = df_grocery[df_grocery['[SUB CATEGORY]'].str.contains(str(ingName[i]), case=False)]
df_grocery['IngredientName'] = ingName[i]
df_grocery['IngredientID'] = ingID[i]
df_grocery.to_csv("ingred.csv",  mode = 'a', encoding='utf-8', header=None)
```

This is the code that works, had to add str to ingName, and it works, Although currently, it only writes out the first element in the List. But this does Almost everything i need.

Comment: Try adding `regex=False` to the `str.contains`.

Comment: Is there an element of `ingName` which is not a string?

Comment: @EFT no there isn't, I am going to save my csv in another format to see if that helps.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew i did, returned back AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'upper'

Comment: So, your `ingName[i]` is a float? It must be `string`. Try `str(ingName[i])`.

Comment: yes, this was the problem, thank you for the help. I encounter another issue, even though i am looping it, seems it only gets the first element in the array, After 0, it does not iterate to the next value.

Comment: Please share your new code. df_grocery = df_grocery[df_grocery['[SUB CATEGORY]'].str.contains(str(ingName[i]), case=False)] this will overwrite the existing df. Is that what you want ?

Answer (score 0):

Ideally you could have used something like below:

```
for i in xrange(len(ingName)):
    print ingName[i]
    # checks the value of the current element in ingName is present in Sub category.
    indx = df_grocery[df_grocery['[SUB CATEGORY]'] == ingName[i]].index
    # for the rows returned update, the ingredient name and id
    for row in indx:
        df_grocery.loc[row,'IngredientName'] = ingName[i]
        df_grocery.loc[row,'IngredientID'] = ingID[i]
    else:
        print "Element missing"
```

Comment: Hey Tammy thanks,
This seems to add ingName, and ingID to  every rows in the table. i only want it to add the data to rows that either contains the ingredient name, or the substring of it. 

The error also did not go away. Thanks

Comment: @AbidemiOni I modified the answer. Can you please test now ?

Comment: Hey Tammy, not it does not work. It seems ingredientName, and IngredientID isn't appending to the new dataframe